# Uiautomator is not getting open by double clicking on

Tags: android-uiautomator, appium-android

I have downloaded all SDK packages required for Emulator but still my UIautomatorviewer window is not getting open by double clicking. also i have added environment variable for platform tools, tools, tools/bin

Comment: SDK on windows?

Comment: yes on windows 7

Comment: I remember some version of sdk on windows has issue? You need open cmd, and in cmd to execute `uiautomatorviewer.bat`, this will give you information why the bat fail to launch. You may need to change some part of your `uiautomatorviewer.bat`

Comment: i have execute that command & error displayed as

Comment: C:\Users\Radamatic8>uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Open `uiautomatorviewer.bat`, echo "%java_exe%"
echo "%javaextdirs%"
echo "%prog_dir%"
echo "%jarpath%" before end of last line, and rerun to see the info.

Comment: This is a environment related issue, really hard to debug from remote you may need to add `echo` one by one to see what happened for the `bat` yourself according to the error infomation. Or you can update to lastest sdk, on my side, the latest sdk is ok.